# CCAction: Stopping and running

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

For my project, I've created a running character. Currently, I am attempting to implement different animations for the character.

I've decided to create 2 different actions

`1) CCAction *walkAction;`

`2) CCAction *jumpAction;`

When the character is supposed to jump, I call a method that `[self stopAllActions];` and then make it `[self runAction:jumpAction];` When the character lands, I call stopAllActions and then run the walkAction.

For some reason, though, the application freezes up. I need help regarding stopping and running actions without the application crashing!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to give us some code. What is self? Have you tried stopping actions explicitly? By this I mean tagging the action and calling stopActionByTag.

Comment: I got it figured out. Self used to be a CCLayer. Instead I used a sprite to fire the action and stop the actions. It works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to retain actions (what I always read).

Just fire a new one each time.  Cocos2d will clean it up.